# Tkinter navigation with frames

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

Hello,

I'm really stuck with this python code. Maybe you can help me?

I want to navigate pages with the buttons. I have three different frames. Then I press on one button, one frame goes on top of others, but do not hide other frames.

If my question for you isn't clear just try my code, and you will see what I mean.

This code from  but little modified.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import StringVar

LARGE_FONT= ("Verdana", 12)


class Application(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        tk.Tk.wm_title(self, "Title")

        container = tk.Frame(self, width=768, height=1000)
        container.pack(side="top", fill='both' , expand = 1)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (StartPage, PageOne, PageTwo):

            frame = F(container, self)

            self.frames[F] = frame
            #frame.pack()
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0)

        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):

        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()


class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        label = ttk.Label(self, text="Start Page", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

        button = ttk.Button(self, text="Visit Page 1",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageOne))
        button.pack()

        button2 = ttk.Button(self, text="Visit Page 2",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageTwo))
        button2.pack()


class PageOne(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = ttk.Label(self, text="Page One!!!", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=0,padx=100)

        button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="Back to Home",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        button1.pack()

        button2 = ttk.Button(self, text="Page Two",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageTwo))
        button2.pack()


class PageTwo(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = ttk.Label(self, text="Page Two!!!", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=0,padx=0)

        button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="Back to Home",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        button1.pack()

        button2 = ttk.Button(self, text="Page One",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageOne))
        button2.pack()

        phone = StringVar()
        home = ttk.Radiobutton(self, text='Home', variable=phone, value='home')
        office = ttk.Radiobutton(self, text='Office', variable=phone, value='office')
        cell = ttk.Radiobutton(self, text='Mobile', variable=phone, value='cell')
        home.pack()
        office.pack()
        cell.pack()

app = Application()
app.mainloop()
```

Thank you very much:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell all the frames to use up all available space, so that they cover any frames below them. You do that by using the sticky argument:

```
frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')
```

That tells the frame to stick to the north, south, east and west sides; in other words fill all the space in both directions.